# React-Native not building

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am building my first react-native app and struggling to get it to build successfully. 
I can completed the following:
- I can create the app using react-native init myApp. 
- Added to enviornment variable ANDROID_HOME (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
- Added JAVA_HOME variable (C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_191)
- Under path I added the following: (;C:\Users\fayejako\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe)
-Added Virtual device in Android studio and when i type in termin adb devices it shows up correctly.

What am i missing?!

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCWLI.png)